# How to send multiple arguments to function as one cell

Tags: matlab, arguments, parameter-passing, variadic-functions

I have a function with the form:

```
function t = fun(str1, str2, str3)
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to have the arguments passed to it as one cell containing the 3 arguments. Is there a way to do this? i.e.:

```
args = {str1, str2, str3};
x = fun(args);
```

I'm trying to find something that sets up this type of functionality. I know I could theoretically do `fun(args{1}, args{2}, args{3})` but this isn't quite what I had in mind. I know varargs would work, but only if I were to change the function inputs, which I hope not to have to do. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: What's wrong with starting your function with `str1 = args{1}` etc? Or simply converting your function to use cells in the rest of the code?

Comment: Do you consider using a struct? Maybe it will help you

Comment: @16per9 I haven't;  what would be the advantage of it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
args = {str1, str2, str3};
x = fun(args{:});
```